# How to change pandas DataFrame value after query by some condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the value ,by use iloc
the code like below

```
>>df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,23,45],['x','y','z']],columns=['a','b','c'])

   # df1 result
      a   b   c
   0  1  23  45
   1  x  y   z
>>df1.loc[(df1['a']==1)].iloc[0,2] = 'dd'
# not change
# I want to show
      a   b   c
  0   1   23  dd
  1   x   y   z
```

Comment: can you try `df1.loc[df1['a']==1, 'c'] = 'dd'`, i mean why not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want join `loc` + `iloc` it is not possible, you need chain conditions, see example in [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#dataframes):

```
df1.loc[(df1.index == 0) & (df1['a']==1), df1.columns[2]] = 'dd'
print (df1)
   a   b   c
0  1  23  dd
1  x   y   z
```

Separately it working nice:

```
df1.iloc[0,2] = 'dd'
print (df1)
   a   b   c
0  1  23  dd
1  x   y   z
```

---

```
df1.loc[df1['a']==1,'c'] = 'dd'
print (df1)

   a   b   c
0  1  23  dd
1  x   y   z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.loc[0,'c']='dd'

df1
a   b   c
0  1  23  dd
1  x   y   z
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it lacks the description of the way you followed and why did you think that this will be a good solution. Please edit your question and include the necessary text to help the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
df1.loc[df1['a']==1,'c'] = 'dd'
```

to choose the column c of the row whose 'a' is 1 and then change it to 'dd'.